# Largest Orthogonal circle for a given circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, orthogonality, mathematica

What is the radius of the largest orthogonal circle (as a function of R)that can be constructed for a given circle of radius R?

Definition of Largest circle-the circle that spans the longest section of the circumference of given circle of radius R on it’s convex side

Comment: no upper bound.

Comment: @WillJagy  what if I change the definition of the”largest circle” to the circle that spans the longest section of the circumference on it’s convex side

Comment: @WillJagy i can’t wrap my head around NO UPPER BOUND, rather intuitively, I speculate NO LOWER BOUND

Comment: @user472374: The "largest orthogonal circle" is a straight line through the center. For any other orthogonal *circle*-circle you may have, there's a larger orthogonal *circle*-circle (which has less curvature and is therefore closer to being a straight line). This is what WillJagy means by "no upper bound".

Comment: @Blue Yeah, I get it now

Answer (score 1):

[image]

For any (true) circle orthogonal to a given circle, you can always find a larger one, with ever-more of the given circle's circumference on its "convex side". So, *there is no "largest" (true) circle*.

Now, larger and larger circles have smaller and smaller curvature; larger and larger *orthogonal* circles get closer and closer to the center of the given circle. Thus, this sequence of circles, as they say, "tend toward" a straight line through the given circle's center. It's sometimes philosophically helpful to consider a line to be a circle, just one of *infinite* radius. (A number of theorems become easier to state.) In *that* sense, the "largest circle" is that line through the center.